# How to update react context after pulling data from firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hey everyone pretty new to React hooks. I am simply trying to set some reviews that I retrieve from Firebase but cant seem to get it working. I tried a few solutions and I am struggling to get it working any help would be appreciated.

```
import React, {useContext, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import firebase from "firebase";
import ReviewsContext from "./review-context";

const Reviews = () => {
const db = firebase.firestore();
let reviews = useContext(ReviewsContext);
let [reviewsLoaded, setReviewsLoaded] = useState(false);

function getReviews(){
  db.collection('reviews')
    .get()
    .then((snapshot) => {
      let dataArray = [];

      snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
        dataArray.push(doc.data());
      });

      reviews = dataArray;
      setReviewsLoaded(true);
      console.log('reviews', reviews); // logs the correct amount of reviews
    })
  }

  function renderReviews() {
  console.log('renderReviews reviewsLoaded', reviewsLoaded); // is true
  console.log('renderReviews reviews length', reviews.length); // is 0
  if(reviewsLoaded) {
    reviews.map((data) => {
      return (
        <li key={data.name}>
          <h3>{data.name}</h3>
          <p>{data.position}</p>
        </li>
      )
    });
  }
  else {
    return false
   }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getReviews(); // this seems to fire before renderReviews
  }, []);


  return (
   <div>
     <ul>
       {renderReviews()}
     </ul>
   </div>
  )
};

export default Reviews;
```

Comment: You don't need context in your given example. Store the `reviews` in state and call `setReviews` once the data loads.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the context should be stateful. The way you're doing it currently won't work since context on render will always revert to reviews being empty. Your `Provider` component that gives that `ReviewContext` should be patterned like below.

```js
import React, { createContext, useState } from "react"

const ReviewContext = createContext()

const ReviewProvider = ({children}) => {

  const [reviews, setReviews] = useState([])

  return (
    <ReviewContext.Provider value={{
      reviews: reviews,
      setReviews: reviews => setReviews(reviews),
    }}>
      {children}
    </ReviewContext.Provider> 
  )
}

export default ReviewProvider
export { ReviewContext }
```

Now, you may do `const { reviews, setReviews } = useContext(ReviewContext);` Just call setReviews whenever you want to update reviews in the context.

It's actually stated in the docs as well as I searched it. https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#dynamic-context